# Top to Bottom Collection View Flow Layout with first cell starting at bottom

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I am trying to mimic Instagram live comments section where the first cell in the `UICollectionView` appears at the bottom but the flow is still top to bottom.  I.e. everything about the flow layout is the exact same except that the first cell is at position `(x: 0, y: heightOfCollectionView)`...

Below is my naive implementation.  I also thought about having the collection view increment in height per item in the `UICollectionView` until the`maxY >= centerY` of the `superview`.

```
import UIKit

class CommentsLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
    let layoutAttribute = super.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)?.copy() as! UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes
    if indexPath.section == 1 {
        print(collectionView?.frame.size.height)
        layoutAttribute.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 600, width: collectionViewContentSize.width, height: 40)
    }
    return layoutAttribute
}
```

}

Comment: Why don't you just reverse your data model collection?

Comment: @VadimPopov I want the very first cell to be inserted at the bottom and all cells after that to be inserted at the bottom -- UICollectionViewFlowLayout has it such that if you have a UICollectionView with some height (600) your items will display at the top (origin).  Reversing the data model will actually create the opposite effect when you get towards the bottom.

Comment: @Jerome did you find any solution to this problem?